# How to autofill email and password at the same time?

Tags: flutter, dart, autofill

When I click the autofill on my email TextFormField, I want both email and password to be autofilled. However, my app only auto-fills the email when I autofill, and I have to click on the password TextFormFieldto autofill it.

```
//email
child: TextFormField(
                          autofillHints: [AutofillHints.email],
),
//password
 child: TextFormField(
                          autofillHints: [AutofillHints.password],
                          onEditingComplete: () =>
                              TextInput.finishAutofillContext(),
),
```

How can i make both fields autofill at once?

Answer (score 1):

Use `AutofillHints.username` instead of `AutofillHints.email`. E-mail autofill only indicates that the field holds an e-mail address but if you use e-mail and password for authentication, you have to use `AutofillHints.username`.

**EDIT: example**

```
child: AutofillGroup(
  child: Column(
    children: <Widget>[
      TextFormField(
        keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
        autocorrect: false,
        textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
        autofillHints: const [
          AutofillHints.username,
          AutofillHints.email
        ],
        textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.none,
      ),
      TextFormField(
        keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
        textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
        autofillHints: const [AutofillHints.password],
        obscureText: true,
      ),

    ],
  ),
)),
```

Comment: It still doesnt autofill both at the same time

Comment: Do you have these fields wrapped into an `AutofillGroup`? A will add a complete example to the answer how I use these, hope it helps.

Comment: Ah I have to wrap it

Comment: Yes, look at the example I added to my answer. For me it works this way.

Comment: What if i need to put a sized boxed between the 2 fields?

Comment: Simply add between the fields: `const SizedBox(height: 16.0)`